# cant seem to convert array to JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

So im working on this piechart google visulization with php and javascript, but i cant seem to get the json convertion to work.

Here is my php code:

```
$sql = "select pNavn, antallTimer from Prosjekter where userId=".$userId;
$result = hentData($sql);
$orders = array(array('Prosjekt navn', 'Antall Timer'));
/* Extract the information from $result */
while ( $rad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $temp = array($rad['pNavn'], $rad['antallTimer']);
    array_push($orders, $temp);
}
$orders=json_encode($orders);
var_dump($orders);
```

i have looked a bit here on SO but the convertion that people say are working i cant seem to get to work. i have tried:

```
json_encode(
    iconv(
        mb_detect_encoding($orders, mb_detect_order(), true),
        'UTF-8',
        $orders
    )
)
```

and

```
mb_convert_variables('utf-8', 'original encode', array/object)
```

the first gives error cause of `$orders` beeing an array and not string, and the second didnt give any error but the `var_dump` of `$orders` is still false.

The var_dumps im getting:

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Prosjekt navn' (length=13)
  1 => string 'Antall Timer' (length=12)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Mitt F�rste Prosjekt' (length=20)
  1 => string '72' (length=2)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Mitt Andre Prosjekt' (length=19)
  1 => string '20' (length=2)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'MItt tredje prosjekt' (length=20)
  1 => string '5' (length=1)
4 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'et fjerde prosjekt' (length=18)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
```

what i need help with is making the JSON working with this [piechart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)
Please help, getting desperate here:)

Comment: What JSON output are you getting from your var_dump? What JSON output are you wanting to get from it?

Comment: the var dump i get from the var dump is this: C:\wamp\www\php\php prosjekt 16\statistikk.php:21:boolean false

What i want is the $orders to become a json string that i can feed into var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
 <?php  echo $orders; ?>
 );
 var options = {
  title: "Timer fordelt på prosjekter"
 };
 var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("timer_piechart"));
 chart.draw(data, options);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and got it to work. Thanks for the help on trying to guide me down the rigth path. It turned out to be an issue of utf-8 encoding. The working code is as follows:

```
$sql = "select pNavn, antallTimer from Prosjekter where userId=".$userId;
    $result = hentData($sql);
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Prosjekt Navn', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Timer', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$temp = array();
$temp[] = array('v' => iconv(mb_detect_encoding($r['pNavn'], mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $r['pNavn']));
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['antallTimer']);
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question what you are wanting the output to be, but it seems like you want to add your values from the mysql fetch to the arrays you created as subarrays of $orders. So maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
$columns = array(
    array('label' => 'Prosjekt navn', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Antall Timer', 'type' => 'number')
);
$orders = array($columns);
/* Extract the information from $result */
while ( $rad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $row = array($rad['pNavn'], $rad['antallTimer']);
    array_push($orders, $row);
}
$orders=json_encode($orders);
var_dump($orders);
```

UPDATE:
Based on your usage of the Google visualization API your JSON data looks incorrect feeding into the arrayToDataTable method. The docs state your data needs to be formatted as in their example:

```
var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{label: 'Country', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Population', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'Area', type: 'number'},
    {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
    ['CN', 1324, 9640821, 'Annotated'],
    ['IN', 1133, 3287263, 'Annotated'],
    ['US', 304, 9629091, 'Annotated'],
    ['ID', 232, 1904569, 'Annotated'],
    ['BR', 187, 8514877, 'Annotated']
]);
```

Based on that format your first row should contain the label and type notations and the rest of the rows should be your data. I have updated the code above to reflect this format. This is untested but should be close to what you need for the Googl visualization API.

Comment: not realy what i was looking for, have updated the question with more info and what im looking for the JSON to work with

Comment: Answer updated to reflect what the Google API needs.